# Having ENTER advance to next field in GTK3 entry fields

Tags: c, linux, gtk3

I have an app that only has a numeric keypad with NO TAB key.  So if the user presses ENTER I would like to accept the input and move to the next field.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the [`activate`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#GtkEntry-activate) signal, and in the handler, move the focus to the next entry.